# How to create shiny app with real time data based on user input?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to create an app that displays based on user input in real time . For this, I am using reactive function. Here is my entire code. The question is somewhat based on Ellis Valentiner but it extends the app little further. The app runs the first iteration but then it is not able to find my_data.

```
    library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

ui <- shinyServer(fluidPage(
  textInput("Somenumber", "Somenumber", value = 5),
  actionButton(inputId = "click", label = "Predict"),
  plotOutput("first_column")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  nameoftext <- reactive({
    data <- eventReactive(input$click, {
      input$Somenumber
    })
    usernumber <- as.numeric(data())
    return(usernumber)
  })

  # Function to get new observations
  get_new_data <- function(){
    numerinumber <- nameoftext()
    data <- rnorm(numerinumber) %>% rbind %>% data.frame
    return(data)
  }

  # Initialize my_data
  my_data <<- reactive({get_new_data()})

  # Function to update my_data
  update_data <- function(){
    my_data <<- rbind(get_new_data(), my_data())
  }



  observeEvent(input$click, {
    # Plot the 30 most recent values
    output$first_column <- renderPlot({
      print("Render")
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
      playthins<- update_data()
      print(my_data())
      appdata <- my_data()
      plot(X1 ~ 1, data=playthins[1:30,], ylim=c(-3, 3), las=1, type="l")
    })
  })


})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Based on Stéphane Laurent's comments, if I remove `<<-`, the data is not appended. So the live line chart does not form over the plot.

If I keep `<<-`, I get following error message.

```
Warning: Error in my_data: could not find function "my_data"
  [No stack trace available]
```

Comment: Why are you using `<<-`?

Comment: Your suggestion helped it to run but the data does not append to the previous data in order to make the live line chart.

Comment: If I do not have `<<-` the data does not get appended. If I have have `<<-`, I get following error message.  `Warning: Error in <<-: cannot change value of locked binding for 'data'
  [No stack trace available]`